# How to deny access to directory contents (IIS served site) via browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have some files kept in `SiteFolder/` which I need to access through the C# project but I do not want them to be listed via browser at those path. How can I accomplish this? Is there any setting in IIS that could be changed?

Also, as I gave full control to IIS user to access/read/write this directory files, what is the solution then?

Basically I do not want anyone to access this directory's content via browser but should be accessible by IIS.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**: This is the file write functionality which should remain unaffected -

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/SiteFolder/example.txt"), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(file))
{
     fileWriter.WriteLine("Something");
}
```

Additionally, as this code is running on Amazon EC2, I had to provide full control of the folder and file to these users -

```
IUSR
MyProjectName
```

Comment: See here for a couple of ideas:
http://serverfault.com/questions/37762/block-access-to-subdirectory-using-web-config

Comment: This only solves the browser access part but now the functionality which writes to those files is also broken.

Comment: You'd have to show your code, then. It's probably running as the requesting user instead of the application's service account. The link I provided is probably more correct than URL rewriting because it deals with securing access to resources vs. just obscuring their locations when requests are made.

Comment: @Colin I was thinking the same. URL rewriting is probably more intended to hide method names/request params. Can you please tell what info do you need from me?

Comment: When you said "the functionality which writes to those files is also broken", can you show the "broken" block of code and describe the context where it is used (is it in a call to service, is it in a page controller)? Also, is impersonation enabled or how are users authenticated/authorized?

Comment: @Colin Please see edit 1 above. That code is in a controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you're impersonating the caller when trying to write to the file in question. Otherwise, if you were running as the system account, it doesn't seem like write permission should be affected.

Therefore, what I suggest in addition to the configuration mentioned above (https://serverfault.com/questions/37762/block-access-to-subdirectory-using-web-config) is to run the code block that writes the file as the system account by temporarily undoing impersonation like this:

```
using (System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext wic = 
     System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    FileStream file = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/SiteFolder/example.txt"), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
    using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
         fileWriter.WriteLine("Something");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your utilizing a default Internet Information System, the default folder `wwwroot` is locked directly to the designated user through your `Application Pool`.  Which in most instances, will be a *Network Service Account*.

Your specific application will have a degree of permission, but your web-application by default shouldn't have access to the other contents of `wwwroot`.

The directory would be:

```
inetpub - wwwroot - Example
inetpub - wwwroot - Demo
```

So `Example` and `Demo` are both two separate web-sites that are hosted.  So if you attempt to navigate to another directory, from one application, it should protect you automatically.

However, if you need to block a web-site from particular users or an application it is indeed possible.  In the current state, the question is too broad.

- Request Filtering
- URL Rewrite

Those are two approaches, however if your utilizing *Virtual Directories* you should take a look at the following [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis).

Without a Virtual Directory, my above protection stands true:

> A site is a container for applications and virtual directories, and
>   you can access it through one or more unique bindings.
>
> The binding includes two attributes important for communication: the
>   binding protocol and the binding information. The binding protocol
>   defines the protocol over which communication between the server and
>   client occurs. The binding information defines the information that is
>   used to access the site. For example, the binding protocol of a Web
>   site can be either HTTP or HTTPS, and the binding information is the
>   combination of IP address, port, and optional host header.

Comment: Well, I tried request filtering approach but it seems to also deny access to the code. I am not using Virtual Directories for now, but looks like a pretty clean solution to me. I just want to restrict browser access to say example.com/SiteFolder/file.txt but seems there is no simple way to achieve this.

Comment: You can use a URL Rewrite to block access to that path.

Comment: Sure, I am going to try that.

Comment: I read about the URL rewriting approach but that this is not what I am intending to do. I just want to deny access to a server resource and not redirect/rewrite the user to another path.